# Подобрать правильный локатор

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python-2.7

Всем привет.
Я еще только учусь, но уже столкнулся с проблемой (для меня это проблема), которая выносит мне мозг третий день. Перегуглил все что можно(по идее) и не смог найти внятного ответа.
Вобщем суть такая.
Есть таблица:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr><td>...</td></tr> --- таких элементов очень много все они похожи на нижние
<tr bgcolor="#EFEFEF">

    <td class="content">Пол:</td>
    <td colspan="3" class="content">
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="M" id="sex">
        М
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="F" id="sex">
        Ж
</tr>

<tr bgcolor="#EFEFEF">

    <td class="content">Паспортные данные:</td>
    <td colspan="3" class="content">ЗР 316350
</tr>
</table>
```

Вопрос в том, как вытягивать весь текст из тега ? Из всех тегов .

Пробовал так

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table/tr/td[@class='content']").text
```

не получается.

Answer (score 1):

Так пробовали?

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table/tr/td[@class='content']").get_attribute('innerHTML')
```